# Unexpected token error when using Gulp babelify to process ReactJS JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, babeljs

I tried to use `gulpfiles.js -- from [New ES6 project with Babel, Browserify & Gulp](https://gist.github.com/danharper/3ca2273125f500429945)

`app.js` is set as "./static/js/xblockchat.js" and shown below:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var config = require('./config');
// require('./chatUI');


var test = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div> HELLO, HAOYU </div>
    );
  }
});


function ChatXBlock(runtime, element) {
    $(function ($) {
        console.log(element);
        ReactDOM.render(
            <test />,
            document.getElementById('content')
        );
        /* Here's where you'd do things on page load. */
    });
}
```

However, when I run `gulp build`, it gives me error below: The line 11 is pointed to `<div> HELLO, HAOYU </div>`. Therefore, the error should be related babel.

```
{ [SyntaxError: /Users/haoyuchen/Developer/xblock_development/xblockchat/xblockchat/static/js/xblockchat.js: Unexpected token (12:6) while parsing file: /Users/haoyuchen/Developer/xblock_development/xblockchat/xblockchat/static/js/xblockchat.js]
  pos: 223,
  loc: { line: 12, column: 6 },
  _babel: true,
  codeFrame: '\u001b[0m  10 |   render\u001b[1m:\u001b[22m \u001b[36mfunction\u001b[39m\u001b[34m\u001b[1m(\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[34m\u001b[1m)\u001b[22m\u001b[39m \u001b[32m{\u001b[39m\n  11 |     \u001b[36mreturn\u001b[39m \u001b[34m\u001b[1m(\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n> 12 |       \u001b[1m<\u001b[22mdiv\u001b[1m>\u001b[22m HELLO\u001b[1m,\u001b[22m HAOYU \u001b[1m<\u001b[22m\u001b[1m/\u001b[22mdiv\u001b[1m>\u001b[22m\n     |       ^\n  13 |     \u001b[34m\u001b[1m)\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[1m;\u001b[22m\n  14 |   \u001b[32m}\u001b[39m\n  15 | \u001b[32m}\u001b[39m\u001b[34m\u001b[1m)\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[1m;\u001b[22m\u001b[0m',
  filename: '/Users/haoyuchen/Developer/xblock_development/xblockchat/xblockchat/static/js/xblockchat.js',
  stream: 
   { _readableState: 
      { objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: [Object],
        pipesCount: 1,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        data: [Function: ondata],
        _mutate: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      { objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _options: { objectMode: true },
     _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
     _streams: [ [Object] ],
     length: 1,
     label: 'deps' } }
```

This is my first time to use babel and Can anyone help me find what's wrong here?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar task in my gulpfile, the key difference is that the `transform` is passed as an option to `browserify`:

```
var bundler = browserify({ 
    entries : './src/index.js',
    debug: true,
    transform : [ babel ]
});
return bundler.bundle()
  .pipe(source('index.js'))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
```

Comment: Instead of using babel, adding reactify into transform solves my problem! Temporarily